# Salesforce Static attribute fetching user saved value

Tags: salesforce, apex

Assume I am on a Salesforce sandbox containing a managed package, that Managed Package has a before insert trigger that defaults the value of a picklist to valueA in the Managed package.

I have created my before Insert event and I am retrieving the value that the user entered, assume ValueUser and assigning it to a static attribute s_a on another class.

When reviewing the debug log, I see the following:
1- My before insert trigger fires the first time pull the ValueUser and assign it the static attribute s_a as expected
2- the before insert trigger fires a second time and the s_a comes blank this time

how can I make sure that the ValueUser is saved during the first time to s_a , and be able to fetch that value even though multiple other Managed package before insert trigger fired afterwards.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. The order of multiple trigger execution is not guaranteed. Can you share what business requirement you are trying to achieve with the trigger? It might help to draw some suggestion for an alternative approach.

Comment: As @KosukeSakai stated, trigger order is not guaranteed at all. You will need to add a validation rule or workflow rule that sets this field before it is saved to ensure your field is set, that way the managed package trigger won't default it to a certain value.